# Need help in converting if else and then do function to python from sas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

My data is in below format and i want to create my below code which is dependent on this data to Python code. I am finding it difficult to proceed.

```
data out1 out2;
    set Input 
    if excl=0 and strip(segment) ne "segment";
        if intck("month",vardate,'30Jun2008'd)<0 and intck("month",vardate,'31Mar2010'd)>=0 then do;
        Rec=1;
        red=0;
    end;
    else if intck("month",vardate,'31Mar2010'd)<0 and intck("month",vardate,'30Sep2013'D)>=0 then do;
        Rec=0;
        red=1;
    end;
    else do;
        Rec=0;
        red=0;
    end;
        if vardate in ('30Jun2008'd,'30Jun2009'd,'30Jun2012'd,'30Jun2014'd) or intck("month",vardate,'30Jun2016'd)<=0 then output out2;
    else output out1;
run;
```

[image]

I tried writing this piece of code to start but did not work.NOw this is my code.

```
recession = 0
recovery = 0

if data['excl_flg'] == 0 and data['segment'] != 'not modeled':
    if (data['snapdate'].dt.to_period('M') - '2008-06-30'.dt.to_period('M')) < 0 & (data['snapdate'].dt.to_period('M') - '31Mar2010'.dt.to_period('M') >= 0:
         recession = 1
    elif (data['snapdate'].dt.to_period('M') - '31Mar2010'.dt.to_period('M')) < 0 and (data['snapdate'].dt.to_period('M') - '30Sep2013'.dt.to_period('M')) >= 0:
        recovery = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots going on here:

- `&` is the bitwise and operator. You want the `and` [logical operator](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).
- `IGNORE` does not match the data in your picture, which shows `ignore`.
- `VARDATE` does not match the data in your picture, which shows `vardate`.
- When an `if` statement in SAS has a `do`, everything until the `end` is a part of that `if`.
- Indentation matters in Python.

Try this Python for the first part of the SAS code:

```
rec = 0
red = 0

if data['excl'] = 0 and data['segment'] != 'ignore':
    if (data['vardate'].dt.to_period('M') - '30Jun2008'.dt.to_period('M')) < 0 and (data['vardate'].dt.to_period('M') - '30Jun2010'.dt.to_period('M') >= 0:
        rec = 1
    elif (data['vardate'].dt.to_period('M') - '30Jun2010'.dt.to_period('M')) < 0 and (data['vardate'].dt.to_period('M') - '30Jun2013'.dt.to_period('M')) >= 0:
        red = 1
```

Caveat: Python is not my first language. And, I don't know anything about Panda, which you appear to be using to convert date strings into period intervals. So, I cannot vouch for the date logic. Also, I've not done SAS in a very long time.

That should be enough to get you started, though.

Comment: I get this error when i run suggested code.  File "<ipython-input-9-62293f9c29cb>", line 5
    if (data['snapdate'].dt.to_period('M') - '30Jun2008'.dt.to_period('M')) < 0 & (data['snapdate'].dt.to_period('M') - '31Mar2010'.dt.to_period('M') >= 0:
                                                                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Right. I expected that. You should research how Python expects dates to be formatted so that `.dt.to_period` can understand them.